# Поиск равных сигнатур в последовательности

Tags: c#

Есть строка с числами, по типу 1,2,3, в которых могут быть любые числа. Мне нужно проверить, есть ли в строке `<любое число>,255,<любое число>`. И если есть, то нужно проверить - равны ли два, или более найденных чисел друг другу, выполняя определенное действие. Например `1,255,0`, `1,255,0` и `123,255,0` - первые два значения равны и действие выполнится.

При этом 255 может появляться и в первом/последнем числе, но действия должны выполняться только тогда, когда 255 появляется во втором. Также 255 может встречаться более двух раз, а может и ни разу. Если, например, значений с 255 посередине будет десять - нужно сравнить их всех и если в двух (или более) будут одинаковые **первые** числа - выполнить действие. Ну и напоследок: необязательно использовать Regex, главное - результат! Я его использую, потому-что ничего другого не нашёл.
Забыл также сказать, что каждые три числа идёт символ ~, то есть `1,2,3~1,225,0~1,1,1`

Мой код на данный момент:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(\w*),255,");
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(txt);
```

Comment: Простите, но вам точно нужно это делать через regex'пы? Мне кажется, что правильнее перевести вашу строку из формата "цифры через запятую" в IEnumerable<int> и уже в этой последовательности ковыряться. И вопрос ваш очень сильно неполон. Что делать если во входных данных 255 встречается пять раз? Может ли встретиться более одного раза или не может? А что делать, если 255 первым числом и перед ним ничего нет? А если последним? Это все очевидные вопросы, которые хороший программист должен задавать перед тем, как решать задачу иначе потом на практике всплывёт и придётся переделывать.

Comment: Вообще задание не понял

Comment: @АндрейNOP Есть IEnumerable<int> в котором изредка проскакивает магическое число 255. При появлении его нужно сравнить prev и next элементы, если равны, то произвести действие (например, вывести в консоль диагностическое сообщение). Как-то так вижу.

Comment: @AK, ну тогда просто, надо взять Windowed из MoreLinq с окном по 3, с Where по window[1]==255

Comment: Можно и регуляркой, что-то типа `,(\d+),255,\1,`

Comment: @AK Прошу прощения. Пост дополнил.

Comment: @АндрейNOP М, адские linq-однострочники! :) Я бы плюсанул такой ответ, но мне кажется, что простой цикл for вполне по силам и топикстартеру. Посмотрим, как он уточнит задачу, пока интрига сохраняется.

Comment: то есть 1,2,3,255,1,2,3 - верно, а 2,2,3,255,1,2,3 - не верно?

Comment: Вы бы хоть примеры привели с входными и выходными данными, а то это как гадание на кофейной гуще

Comment: Уточните вопрос, вам нужно смотреть числа ДО и ПОСЛЕ 255 или вам важно только число перед 255? Допустим, в последовательности 1,1,1,2,255,1,1,1,2,255,1,1,1,3,255,1 вам важно только сравнивать между собой числа перед 255? То есть вы ловите сигнатуры из двух чисел, при этом первое число может быть любым, второе всегда 255 и вам нужно все найденные сигнатуры сравнить и найти те первые цифры, которые встречаются более одного раза?

Comment: @AK Мне нужно только число ПЕРЕД 255.

Comment: А если будет ...1~255,1,0~... - это подходит под ваш ответ, ведь 1 и с права, и слева?

Comment: @VladimirAfanasyev Нет, мне нужно непосредственно цифры между ~. 1~255,1,0~ не подходит, ведь в данном случае 255 должна считаться первым числом!

Comment: Обновил ответ для вас

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Топорный вариант (если я правильно понял ваш вопрос), но без `regexp`, так как не понимаю зачем он тут вообще. Но и этот вариант не очень хорош, потому что в для отсутствия ошибок надо будет кастить правое и левое значение, т.к. если они не кастятся в инт автоматом, то придется пропускать/выдавать ошибку, так как при таком условии он будет сравнивать стринги, а не инты:

```
string s = "45,255,32,34,255,34,255,34";
string[] parse = s.Split(",");
   for (int i = 1; i<parse.Length-1; i++)
   {
      if (parse[i-1] == parse[i+1] && parse[i] == "255")
         Console.WriteLine("На позиции " + i + " стоит 255, правый и левый элемент от которого равны");
   }
```

Вывод:

```
На позиции 4 стоит 255, правый и левый элемент от которого равны
На позиции 6 стоит 255, правый и левый элемент от которого равны
```

upd:

```
string s = "45,255,32~34,255,34~255,34,4";
foreach (string element in s.Split("~"))
{
   string[] values = element.Split(",");
   if (Convert.ToInt32(values[1]) == 255 && Convert.ToInt32(values[0]) == Convert.ToInt32(values[2]))
      Console.WriteLine(element);
}
```

upd2:

```
string s = "45,255,32~34,255,34~255,34,4";
List<int> nums = new List<int>();


foreach (string element in s.Split("~"))
{
   string[] values = element.Split(",");
   if (Convert.ToInt32(values[1]) == 255)
      if (nums.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(values[0])))
         Console.WriteLine("Есть совпадение по первому значению");
      else nums.Add(Convert.ToInt32(values[0]));
}
```

Comment: На сколько я понял, этот код проверяет равны ли первое и третье числа, но мне же нужно, чтобы он сравнивал первые числа всех значений из строки, у которых 255 - второе число.

Comment: @Mortmael Вы разберитесь в коде, а потом говорите о том, как код работает:) На основе вашего ответа понимаю, что вы даже не пытались его запустить. Вам дали решение, а вы его даже запустить не хотите - странно:)

Comment: Я запускал. И ещё раз запустил, проанализировав! В коде явно видно проверку первого и третьего элементов, вместо проверки только первых во всех значениях. Также, если запустить код, выводятся только те значения, в которых первые и третьи - одинаковы...

Comment: @Mortmael так вам надо чтобы брались группы по 3 элемента (те, что между ~) и сравнивались первые значения каждой группы? Или чтобы первое и третье значение в группе проверялось на равенство?

Comment: Да, именно так - первые элементы групп.

Comment: @Mortmael если б вы хотели понять действительно код, а не получить решение, то переработать первую версию в ваш результат - не проблема. А пока что вы хотите получить просто результат, ничего не сделав

Comment: @Mortmael вам надо найти все тройки, где 255 на первом месте, при этом чтобы хотя бы одна пара из этих троек содержала одинаковую первую цифру?

Comment: Если бы я мог - я бы с радостью переработал код, но я не понимаю, а потому и обратился сюда.
Если под первым местом вы подразумеваете вторую цифру, то да

Comment: @Mortmael не надо списывать свое нежелание разобраться на свое неумение:) Вам достаточно сказали в комментариях, чтобы решить ваш вопрос. p.s. обновил ответ